# The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/InsuranceProvider] but context failed to start

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, devops, ubuntu-18.04, tomcat9

I am trying to deploy the war file on tomcat using jenkins on ubuntu machine.
Using:

- jdk 1.8
- tomcat 9

Can able to create .war file successfully inside webapps folder but while deploying, its failing. Also can able to see my .war context path in tomcat manager page but whaile accessing I'm getting 404.

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception  
 org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to deploy [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/First/target/InsuranceProvider.war]  
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:104)  
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:172)  
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)  
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)  
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)  
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1165)  
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1148)  
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)  
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)  
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)  
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)  
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:80)  
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)  
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:803)  
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:752)  
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1072)  
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:697)  
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1931)  
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)  
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)  
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)  
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/InsuranceProvider] but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message  
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:721)  
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:767)  
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:312)  
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:99)  
    ... 20 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The **Tomcat Manager responded "FAIL - Deployed application at context path [/InsuranceProvider] but context failed to start
" instead of the expected "OK" message**  
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:721)  
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:767)  
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:312)  
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.deploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:99) 
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:172)  
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:81)  
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:167)  
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:136)  
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1165)  
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1148)  
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeployFile(CargoContainerAdapter.java:133)  
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeployFile(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:95)  
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:113)  
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)  
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:80)  
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)  
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:803)  
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:752)  
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1072)  
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:697)  
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1931)  
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)  
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)  
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)  
 Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```